# How to set the cursor at end in edittext

Tags: android

Whenever i touch the edittext, cursor should be at end.Even if the editText is already having some text and it should not allow to move left awards

```
 editTextView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                    editTextView.onTouchEvent(event);

                    if(!textFocus) {
                        editTextView.setSelection(editTextView.getText().length());
                        textFocus = true;
                    }

                    return true;
                }
            });

            editTextView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                    textFocus = false;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 19):

This is helped me. Always when i touch the edittext the cursor will be at the end

```
editTextView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    editTextView.onTouchEvent(event);
                    editTextView.setSelection(editTextView.getText().length());
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Comment: In newer versions API User can drag using handle, In that case I'ts not working.

Answer (score 7):

You can extend EditText and override onSelectionChanged function.

For example:

```
    public class CustomEditText extends EditText {
         public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
             super(context, attrs);
         }

         public CustomEditText(Context context) {
             super(context);
         }

         public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
             super(context, attrs, defStyle);
         }

         @Override 
         protected void onSelectionChanged(int selStart, int selEnd) {
              this.setSelection(this.getText().length());
         }
    }
```

In XML you should then use yourpackagename.CustomEditText instead of EditText.

Answer (score 4):

Try one of below code snippet, it should work

```
a)

   editText.setText("Your text");
   editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());
b)

   editText.setText("");    
   editText.append("Your text");

c)

   editText.append("");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
editText.setTextKeepState(CharSequence text)
```

to set the text to be displayed but retain the cursor position.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no such method to do this directly, but on can do this,

```
editText.setText(editText.getText().toString);
```

on focus Change or where ever you want to.