# Xamarin Forms. How I can focus on the end of entry when I press the button?

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.android

```
private void Sum(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddSign('+');
        calculatorString.Focus();
    }
```

After pressing button I want to focus on the end of entry.
[Image with design of app, xaml code and description of my problem :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5V26.png)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have to create a CustomRenderer. Here some notes

[Entry CustomRenderer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/entry/)

Then you should use [setSelection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39590423/how-to-set-the-cursor-at-end-in-edittext)